# How can I hide page elements till an AJAX call completes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am writing HTML that looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
    <div style='visibility:hidden;' id='my_grad'>
        <svg>
            <!-- The SVG element I want to hide until the data for the chart
                 in chart_div is obtained and the chart renders -->
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript, I have tried both of the following AJAX calls:

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/path/to/source/data',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        // Parse data and create chart (for chart_div).
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        $('#my_grad').show();
    }
});
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/path/to/source/data',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        // Parse data and create chart (for chart_div).
    }
}).done(function(){
    $("#my_grad").show(); 
});
```

---

The problem is that although the SVG element is hidden as it is supposed to be initially, it fails to be shown after the charts are loaded in both cases.

How can I make a CSS portion of a page wait till the AJAX call finishes to appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `#` to indicate your jQuery selector is targeting an `id` attribute for an HTML Element.

Use the following:

```
$('#my_grad').show()
```

Further, you need to change the `visibility:hidden;` property to `display:none;`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9fm7f08/2/)

For reference, to target any `id` attribute with a jQuery selector you need to prefix a `#` sign before the value of the attribute. For a `class` selector use a `.` prefix. Without either you are targeting a *tag* of the specified name; in this case you'd be trying to target the tag `<my_grad>`.

Ex:

`$('#my_grad').show()` <==> `<div id="my_grad">`

`$('.my_grad').show()` <==> `<div class="my_grad">`

`$('my_grad').show()` <==> `<my_grad>`

Comment: Hmmm...  Thanks for pointing that out.  That was a problem, but even after fixing that, it still doesn't show (in both cases shown in the OP).

Comment: Though @AlienHoboken's answer isn't wrong, it is incomplete. @rolo1091's answer is the correct one, jQuery's `show` method sets the `display` css property to `block`, and does not change `visibility`

Comment: @RobM. you're correct, I was just adding that while you commented. :)

Comment: @RobM. @AlienHoboken So changing `visibility:hidden` to `display:none` results in the SVG element appearing before the chart does, though it does appear to be slower in appearing than it would be otherwise.  What is the difference between the two cases I'm showing in my OP?

Comment: Nothing much, though callbacks are applied before promises are resolved within jQuery. If your chart rendering is dependent on the ajax request and takes time to setup, perhaps there is a success/draw/init/etc. callback of your charting library that you could use to `.show()` your svg.

Comment: I'm looking now, but for reference, I'm using Google Charts.

Comment: I was about to say something along the lines of what Rob said. It's possible that the `complete` callback is getting triggered before you are done drawing your chart, as it should get called when the Ajax call returns. Perhaps you should show the SVG after you are done drawing the chart either by using a callback in the charting library as Rob said or just moving the show for the SVG after the charting code.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Adding a listener ([reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events)) for when the chart is ready fixes the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use "style=display:none" instead of "style=visibility:hidden"

And you are missing the # character to refer your id

Comment: Using `style=display:none` results in the SVG showing up before the chart. (P.S. I've fixed the OP to add the `#` since it still doesn't work even with that included.)